# USB switch Connections USB A to A vs. USB A to C

Tags: usb, switch, kvm-switch

I have recently bought a USB switch that allows me to switch USB devices instantaneously between computers. That being the case, I have noticed that the USB switch I have currently uses a USB Male A to Male A for connecting the computers to the switch. Through researching on the internet, it seems that this setup is not supported by USB specifications and can pose potential risks. Is this true?

Also, I have seen USB switches that use USB C to C connect the computers to the device. Would buying and using a USB A Male to C Male cable to connect the computers to the device be safe if getting this version?

I have heard so many different things, so getting an updated answer on here would be great.

Comment: It’s unsupported but it’s not unsafe. USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 is fairly low voltage compared to USB 3.2 Gen 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the USB switch I have currently uses a USB Male A to Male A for connecting the computers to the switch. Through researching on the internet, it seems that this setup is not supported by USB specifications and can pose potential risks. Is this true?

Yes, specifically the cable, not the overall setup.

In A/B ports, normally the A port always supplies power – the upstream ports in your switch don't, but normal A ports do. So if the A-to-A cable has all pins wired end-to-end, there is a risk of the nonstandard cable being accidentally connected to *normal* type-A ports and both devices trying to supply power to each other at once, which might cause issues.

In other words, the overall setup is not at risk of exploding but the nonstandard cable has no safeguard against accidental misuse. ("Just don't do that then" is not a very good safeguard.)

If it's a "data only" cable it's probably safe against such accidents, but that doesn't make it a good design.

> Also, I have seen USB switches that use USB C to C connect the computers to the device. Would buying and using a USB A Male to C Male cable to connect the computers to the device be safe if getting this version?

USB C connectors have a separate signal for power supply, so a proper A-male-to-C cable is safe in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I really appreciate your insight!